# How to make the close button at the bottom-right side using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using flash to display a message, but the button right next to the text rather than in the bottom-right.  How do I relocate the button?

```
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <%= success %>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
        </div>
```

[image]

Also, I want to make the button look more like this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/close-button/

Answer (score 1):

You need the respective CSS and JS files.

[Get started with Bootstrap · Bootstrap v5.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <%= success %>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the class. text-right on the containing element to right align your Bootstrap buttons within a block box or grid column. It will work in both Bootstrap 3 and 4 versions.
Or you can just add the align-self-end class to the item to align at the bottom.

Comment: OP isn't using B3 or B4 so `.text-right` would be invalid. `.text-end` is the one you're looking for.

Comment: You don't need any of that + OP tagged their question with [tag:bootstrap-5] which implies they are not using Bootstrap 3 or 4.

Comment: The solution that you mention is from a different version of Bootstrap.